# Oauth2 URL callback Mac Swift 4

Tags: swift, macos, redirect, oauth-2.0, swift4

I am using OAuth 2 into my macOS swift 4 app.

I have successfully implemented the setup of the redirect URI and when the user grants permission, the redirect URI open my mac app using the URL Schemes.

However, there is information in the URL call back that I have been unable to get a method working to catch the redirect.

I've tried these methods in the App Delegate but they don't work:

```
func application(_ application: NSApplication, 
                 open url: URL,
                 sourceApplication: String?,
                 annotation: Any) -> Bool { 

                 //Extract information from URL here
                 }
```

and:

```
func application(_ app: NSApplication, open url: URL) -> Bool {  

                 //Extract information from URL here
                 }
```

What is wrong with these methods?

What method should be used in Swift 4 for a Mac app to catch the call back?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/243-oauth-2-0-with-swift-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer to the question:

```
func application(_ application: NSApplication,
                              open urls: [URL]) {
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplicationdelegate/2887193-application